# Google Earth within custom C++ Linux application

Tags: c++, google-maps, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am exploring using Google Earth within a C++ application I am writing for Linux. This application would be operating at a very high resolution (approx. 6000 x 3000 pixels). I am confident about the graphics performance of Google Earth in the high resolution and the Linux environment. My question is: What is the best way to integrate Google Earth into my Linux C++ application? I have read about the Google Earth COM API (and that it's outdated now). What would be the preferred method to integrate Google Earth into my application?

Specifics for integration: I am hoping to have the Google Earth in the "background" covering the entire 6000 x 3000 resolution with a small "control box" overlay that will interact with the earth.

Thanks for your responses!

kf

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there are only two APIs to access Google Earth content - the Javascript API, and the Windows based C# API (which seem to just be wrapper classes that call the Javascript API.)  I don't know but I believe the Google Maps API to also be in Javascript.

Given that you are in Linux and using C++ my suggestion would be to embed a browser in your app and create C++ wrappers to make the Javascript calls that you need (like the Windows C# API.)

If you start an open source project other people may be willing to help you create C++ wrappers.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that either the [Awesomium](https://awesomium.com) or the [Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/) libraries make embedding a browser for this sort of thing, if not trivial, then much easier than it might at first appear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use a Google Earth Api in Linux. The only API Google Earth offers is the Javascript API (only works in MacOs or Windows, but no Linux) and COM API (seems death now)
It doesn't work even in ChromeOS